# Ckan attr_metadata_store cant be configure via env vars

Tags: fiware-cygnus

I need to set *"cygnus-ngsi.sinks.ckan-sink.attr_metadata_store = false"* via environment variables, but can't find a way to do it.

it's posible?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, it isn't possible. That configuration must go to agent.conf file.

A possible workaround is to use some wrapping script to edit a template agent.conf file based in env var content, similar to what is done to prepare by the Dockefile [entrypoint.sh script](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cygnus/blob/master/docker/cygnus-ngsi/cygnus-entrypoint.sh).